# How should the error-term in reporting results be properly written to make sense?

Tags: standard-deviation, standard-error, error, measurement-error, reporting

I want to report results obtained from a number of measurements with the average value plus minus the standard deviation.
During my studies I was always thaught to use only one signifying digit in the error term and to adapt your average value in such way that it has the same precision as the error term (for example 5.4576 +- 0.0457 becomes 5.46 +-0.05).
The reasoning behind this is that if you are already uncertain about the first signifying digit in the error term, it doesn't make a lot of sense to be more precice on this term. I tend to agree with this logic, yet in many many scientific papers this rule is not applied and I don't seem to find some kind of guidelines how to cope with these cases.

Are there guidelines or what are your opinions?

How should the error-term in reporting results be properly written to make sense?

Comment: Welcome to CV. Note that your username, identicon, & a link to your user page 
are automatically added to every post you make, so there is no need to sign 
your posts. In fact, we prefer you don't.